# How to display products name in a non-alphabetical order, in a custom field (taxonomy)?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy

Now the order is: **apples, oranges, pears**.
But I want to be in a random order, for ex: **oranges, apples, pears**.
Or to write them in a order that I want.

Is this possible?

Taxonomy is like that:

```
        'fruits' => array(
        'post-types' => array('products'),
        'name' => 'Fruits',
        'slug' => 'fruits',
        'type' => 'tags' ),
```

Comment: Show us the whole query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SOLVED] This do the Job:**

```
function set_the_terms_in_order ( $terms, $id, $taxonomy ) {
    $terms = wp_cache_get( $id, "{$taxonomy}_relationships_sorted" );
    if ( false === $terms ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $id, $taxonomy, array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' ) );
        wp_cache_add($id, $terms, $taxonomy . '_relationships_sorted');
    }
    return $terms;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_terms', 'set_the_terms_in_order' , 10, 4 );

function do_the_terms_in_order () {
    global $wp_taxonomies;  //fixed missing semicolon
    // the following relates to tags, but you can add more lines like this for any taxonomy
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->sort = true;
    $wp_taxonomies['post_tag']->args = array( 'orderby' => 'term_order' );    
}
add_action( 'init', 'do_the_terms_in_order');
```

**Credit goes here:** [Change order of Custom Taxonomy List](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7440/change-order-of-custom-taxonomy-list)